# Do we need to have a System.Web section in our IIS web.config file, if we're not using Cassini / Web Development Service?

Tags: iis-7, web.config

a typical `web.config` file has a `<system.web/>` section and a `<system.webServer/>` section.

I'm under the impression that `IIS7 / IIS7 express` ignore the `<system.web/>` section .. so if we will never use that cursed thing called `Cassin/Web Development Server` and only develop against `IIS7 or IIS7 Express`, then can we nuke this section completely from our `web.config` files?

Comment: This question is off-topic under current topicality rules.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you're not using ASP.Net or any related/dependent components, then yes (edit: yes, you *don't* need system.web - that's just for the ASP.Net stuff).

Comment: define 'ASP.NET Stuff' please? ... the website is created in c# + MVC ..... that's pretty ASP.NETy for me...

Comment: The question was on the money. IIS itself uses only the system.webServer section. But the ASP.Net infrastructure, which yes, you're using if you're using c# and MVC, will be controlled by the system.web section. If there's anything in it, assume you probably need it. It'd be like nuking the settings in the system.webServer section otherwise - you'd end up with default settings for that app/website.

Comment: And so re-reading the question: No, system.web isn't just used by Cassini, it's used by ASP.Net. So if you're using *that*, you need it.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, you can. This is also easy to verify: nuke it and test.